# blazor use already present cookies in http requests

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, blazor

I am playing around with Blazor trying to port a rather simple app.
Original project: Web API + JS SPA in a single solution, running on same host/port. It uses Cookie auth as in trying to access index.html or any controller checks the cookie and if it's incorrect/not present, user is redirected to external auth server from which web api gets a callback after user is authenticated, verifies it, getting the claims and logins using a principal made out of the claims.

Client app (Angular) doesn't even have an idea about cookies or authentication, but since it lives on same domain, that cookie from web api authentication is reused in requests to same domain api and thus authenticated.

I tried doing something similar with blazor, I have Server Side blazor solution (Server which has old Web API stuff + blazor calls in the startup + App which is server side Blazor app).
I tried manually navigatting to server's login link, followed the auth flow, the cookie was set. Then tried making request from blazor app to the web api and it failed. Tried adding hard coded Cookie manually and then it worked. So as I understand HttpClient doesn't reuse/has access to browser cookies?

But well, no problem, I thought, I can just make small JS interop to read the cookies and add them to httpclient. Oh wait, the auth cookie has HttpOnly flag and cannot be accessed from JS.

Is it possible to somehow make this setup work without changing authentication in the web api?

Comment: reading HttpOnly cookies is forbidden on the latest version of all major browsers- sounds like you'll need to remove the flag from the cookie to me. You might want to look into using `Request.Cookies` on the server side as that might help you but I don't think you'll find a client side solution

Comment: You should have used JSON Web Tokens in your original Angular application, and this is what you should employ with the Blazor version...